# Previewing PDF inside MUI tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I am trying to display a preview of a PDF inside an MUI `Tooltip` whenever someone hovers over an MUI `ListItem`. I am able to display PNGs and JPGs as previews inside the tooltip using Next.js' `Image` component, but when I tried using `@react-pdf/renderer` to show PDFs, I am only able to display the viewing area of the PDF, but not the PDF itself. My best guess is one of the following: 1) Could it be the URL is not being recognized properly 2) could it be that the PDF is not being saved properly when it's initially uploaded, so there's nothing to display from the URL, 3) It's trying to show the PDF too quickly, so it's not loaded in properly from where it's saved? Below is a minimum reproducible example:

```
const Dropzone = (props) => {
  const { files, setFiles } = props

  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    if (acceptedFiles?.length) {
      setFiles(prev => ([
        ...prev,
        ...acceptedFiles.map(file => (
          Object.assign(file, { preview: URL.createObjectURL(file) })
        ))
      ]))
    }
  }, [])

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop })

  return (
      <List>
        {files.map((file, index) => (
            <Tooltip
              TransitionComponent={Zoom}
              title={
                <PDFViewer>
                   <Document
                     file={file.preview}
                   >
                      <Page pageNumber={1}/>
                  </PDFViewr>
              }
            >
              <ListItem key={file.name}>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <DescriptionIcon />
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={file.name}
                  secondary={file.size}
                />
              </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
        ))}
      </List>

  )
}

export default Dropzone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by instead using the `react-pdf` library. Below is my edited code to be able to display the PDF inside the tooltip. I will preface this though that this will display the PDF properly, but does not include styling it. I also included the drop zone in my answer that I failed to provide in my question

```
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

const Dropzone = (props) => {
  const { files, setFiles } = props

  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    if (acceptedFiles?.length) {
      setFiles(prev => ([
        ...prev,
        ...acceptedFiles.map(file => (
          Object.assign(file, { preview: URL.createObjectURL(file) })
        ))
      ]))
    }
  }, [])

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop })

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box
        {...getRootProps({})
        >
        <input {...getInputProps() />
        <Typography>Drop the files here...</Typography>
      </Box>
      <List>
        {files.map((file, index) => (
          <Tooltip
            TransitionComponent={Zoom}
              title={
                <Document file={file.preview}>
                  <Page pageNumber={1}/>
                </Document> 
              }
            >
              <ListItem key={file.name}>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <DescriptionIcon />
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={file.name}
                  secondary={file.size}
                />
              </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Dropzone
```

Comment: @KJ found an even more reliable solution using react-pdf. It' doesn't convert it into an image, however there are no artifacts below the image. Not the most elegant solution, but it's effective in what I want it to accomplish